# How to make parquet Data Model to list all column using Scala？

Tags: scala, parquet

table and column:

[image]

I am not familiar with Scala,event do not know how to start...I need to write a parquet Data Mode first,and when it map the data to model, it will be stored..

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html - dataframes can be stored as parquet.

Comment: yes,I am trans data from dataframes to parquet format..

Comment: Then what have you tried already?

Comment: Please do not paste sample data (and code) as images. It makes it very difficult for others to recreate your problem.